# задача "ход слона"

Tags: python

Даны две различные клетки шахматной доски, определите, может ли слон попасть с первой клетки на вторую одним ходом. Программа должна вывести `YES`, если из первой клетки ходом слона можно попасть во вторую, или `NO` в противном случае. использовать можно только оператор if

мой код:

```
1x=(int(input())
1y=(int(input())
2x=(int(input())
2y=(int(input())
if (1x==2x)or(1y==2y):
    print("NO")
else:  
    print("YES")
```

выдаёт ошибку

Comment: Ну естественно. Почитайте о соглашениях об именах переменных в питоне. Нельзя, чтобы они начинались с цифр.

Comment: Ну вообще-то слон - это немножко не ладья.

Comment: И кстати, совсем незачем `int`ить переменные, с которыми не производятся операции, специфические для чисел.

Comment: Вот вы изменили вопрос, вас просят использовать "функцию if"? Не оператор? и вроде как приведённое решение от @Глеб решает ошибки в вашем коде.

Comment: В каком питоне `if` стал функцией, не припомню что-то?

Comment: Вы еще раз изменили вопрос, комментриую, в ответе используется оператор `if`

Comment: Тернарный, если быть точным.

Comment: Во первых, добро пожаловать ну ruSO. Сделайте глубокий вдох и выход, вы хотите `слона` или `ладью`? Ваш код (без учёта синтаксиса), описывает поведение ладьи.

Comment: я только учусь.

Comment: Для слона нужно 1) перевести буквы в цифры 2) вычислить разницы между двумя цифрами и двумя буквами 3) проверить, равны ли они.

Comment: x1 = int(input())
y1 = int(input())
x2 = int(input())
y2 = int(input())
if x1 == x2 or y1 == y2:
    print('YES') 
else:
    print('NO')     лодья так

Comment: Да, типа того. Только это все равно ладья.

Comment: @артём это прекрасно, что вы учитесь, давайте учиться вместе. Для начала, я вам рекомендую понять представление того, как слон ходит, какие он действия может выполнять на плоскости шахматной доски по каждой из осей, а уже из этого реализуйте собственный код, который будет выполнять проверку по этим действиям.

Answer (score 1):

По картинке ниже вы сразу поймете, как ходит слон в шахматах.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно заметить, перемещается эта боевая единица по диагонали вперед и назад на любую возможную дистанцию.
Определяем, может ли слон попасть с первой клетки на вторую одним ходом.
для этого пишем:

```
# Ввод полей, сейчас слон на поле e4
m1=input('Введите первое поле например a1 ')
m2=input('Введите второе поле например c3 ')

# chess_board - это буквы внизу шахматной доски
chess_board= 'abcdefgh'

# Определяем на сколько слон переместился по горизонтали
move=(chess_board.index(m1[0]) - chess_board.index(m2[0]))

# Проверяем соответствует ли это перемещению по вертикали 
if int(m1[1])+move == int(m2[1]) or int(m1[1])-move == int(m2[1]):
    print('TRUE')
else:
    print('FALSE')
```

Давайте  протестируем, я не все клетки проверил.

Answer (score 0):

Реальное решение - в одну строку (оператор if). Остальное - только ввод, вывод и отладка.

```
p1=input('Введите первое поле ')
p2=input('Введите второе поле ')
if abs('abcdefgh'.index(p1[0]) - 'abcdefgh'.index(p2[0])) == abs(int(p1[1])-(int(p2[1])))  :
    print('TRUE')
else:
    print('FALSE')
```

Comment: А можно и вывод в одну строку поместить, если через тернар.